# Searching XML file to find if an name exists using c# Winform

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I have a xml file that is not owned by the app I am creating. This xml file has many entries but I am using a cut down version for my development as shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<compliance_data>
  <aircraft_info>
    <aircraft_name>Default</aircraft_name>
    <AftMomentArm>950</AftMomentArm>
    <FwdMomentArm>400</FwdMomentArm>
    <AftCGLimit>560</AftCGLimit>
    <FwdCGLimit>350</FwdCGLimit>
  </aircraft_info>
  <aircraft_info>
    <aircraft_name>MAX8</aircraft_name>
    <AftMomentArm>950</AftMomentArm>
    <FwdMomentArm>400</FwdMomentArm>
    <AftCGLimit>560</AftCGLimit>
    <FwdCGLimit>350</FwdCGLimit>
  </aircraft_info>
  <aircraft_info>
    <aircraft_name>testAircraft</aircraft_name>
    <AftMomentArm>950</AftMomentArm>
    <FwdMomentArm>400</FwdMomentArm>
    <AftCGLimit>560</AftCGLimit>
    <FwdCGLimit>350</FwdCGLimit>
  </aircraft_info>
</compliance_data>
```

My app allows the user to add more aircraft_info to the file but the aircraft_name has to be unique. I planned to get the name from the user then do a quick search to see if the name exists, if it does then I will ask the user to choose another name.

My problem is trying to search the xml I am given. I have tried the following three ways without success. What I would really like is to search and get a bool return true on the first repeat of the name. How can I do this please?

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("compliance_data.xml");
XElement root = new XElement("aircraft_info");

var matches = root
.Descendants("aircraft_info")
.Where(ft => ((string)ft.Element("aircraft_name")) == "Default");

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("compliance_data.xml");

var matches = doc
.Descendants("aircraft_info")
.Where(ft => ((string)ft.Element("aircraft_name")) == "Default");
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"compliance_data.xml");

foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("//aircraft_info[aircraft_name == \"Default\"]/aircraft_name"))
{
    MsgBox.Show(node.InnerText, "abc", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.None); //my 

own customised 

messagebox
}
```

Comment: "I have tried the following three ways without success" What exactly does this mean? What happened with the code you tried?

Comment: Hint: `XElement root = new XElement("aircraft_info");` has nothing to do with the document you've loaded. But your second snippet looks fine... https://gist.github.com/jskeet/37a0b979b59da8ece16867eb1f338a04 for example

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for the brilliant advice. I see I can say if I return matches.Count() as 0 then I can add the data else get another name from user. I have learnt something new today, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I like using a dictionary in this case

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp10
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            Dictionary<string, XElement> dict = doc.Descendants("aircraft_info")
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Element("aircraft_name"), y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
                      
        }
 
        
    }
}
```